# How to get linux user id by user name?

Tags: c, linux

In linux, If I only have the user name, how to get the user id? I used man getuid, but can't find any clues about it.
EDIT1:
Sorry , I want to get the user id by api. I don't like forking a another process to do it such as calling system function.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`getpwnam`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwnam.html) to get a pointer to a `struct passwd` structure, which has `pw_uid` member.  Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *name = "root";
    struct passwd *p;
    if (argc > 1) {
        name = argv[1];
    }
    if ((p = getpwnam(name)) == NULL) {
        perror(name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%d\n", (int) p->pw_uid);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you want a re-entrant function, look into `getpwnam_r`.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use the id command

`id username`

```
[root@my01 ~]# id sylvain
uid=1003(sylvain) gid=1005(sylvain) groups=1005(sylvain)
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `id -u sylvain` returns just the UID, which is the most convenient option in scripts.

Answer (score 4):

All usernames are listed in `/etc/passwd`, so you may grep and cut:

```
grep username /etc/passwd | cut -f3 -d':'
```

Comment: This should works without manually change the username `grep $USER /etc/passwd | cut -f3 -d':'`